# How to make Pillow recognisable by pycharm

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

I installed PIL using pip but get the error.

I used the code below to import Pillow library:

`from PIL import ImageTk,Image`

Any help?

Comment: is pycharm using the right python interpreter?

Comment: yes.. I should installed the library from python terminal so It is installed on virtual environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I needed to install Pillow from my python terminal so that it is installed to the project virtual environment. That solved the problem from me

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm uses a virtual environment for every project. You may have installed PIL outside of your venv. To install it inside, do this.

1. Open your project
2. At the bottom of your screen, hit `Terminal`
3. From there, `pip install -U pillow`

Note: When making the project, you may not have checked the button, `Inherit global site-packages` in the drop down under `Project Interpreter`. If you check it, all the packages on your machine will then be in the Virtual Environment.

Comment: thank you but i should have installed it using pycharm not cmd