# LUbuntu 20.02 PyCharm No Module Named PIL

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to use PyCharm with LUbuntu 20.04. I have Python 3.8.2 installed. My first 2 lines of code are:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

When I run it in Pycharm (version 2020.2 CE) I get the following error:

```
 from PIL import ImageTk, Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

If I open a terminal and run my file with python3 file.py it runs perfectly fine. If I open my file in Idle and press <kbd>F5</kbd> (or run it) it runs fine.

Why would PyCharm throw an error when others don't? I'm sure I'm not including some info you need to answer my question, so let me know what else I can provide.

Comment: Are you sure pycharm is using the same python as idle?

Comment: Are you testing on the same virtual environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm: ImportError no module named X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164669/pycharm-importerror-no-module-named-x)

Comment: And in case the previous link does not answer your question, [searching for "pycharm ModuleNotFoundError"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pycharm+ModuleNotFoundError) currently gives 372 results. Are you sure this question has not been answered before?

Comment: basically pycharm requires u to install the module inside of it itself

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62233609/how-to-make-pillow-recognisable-by-pycharm/62234574#62234574) answer your Q